# Onsenui: sliding menu + google maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, onsen-ui

I trying to use the sliding menu template from onsenui with google maps on one of the pages, but the touch events get messed up? Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the swipe target. eg. only swipe start on the left edge would active the slide.

```
<ons-sliding-menu swipe-target-width="100">
```

Comment: Thanks, but seems is not working. I have this on my code right now:

`<ons-sliding-menu swipe-target-width="100" behind-page="menu.html" above-page="home.html"></ons-sliding-menu>`

Any suggestion?

Comment: may be you are using the old version. This is introduced in 1.0.3

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I'm using monaca, so I updated the version on the config. Thanks!